# SD card rename works...or doesn't..?

Tags: sd-card, dolphin

I slice my 3d printer files to an SD card. Since Cura doesn't give me the opportunity to name the file what I want, I rename the file using Dolphin. Dolphin shows the rename is successful, I can even remove and re-insert the SD card and it shows renamed. When I insert it into my 3D printer, the filename is as Cura saved it, not as it was renamed in Dolphin. What's going on?

Comment: Do you have another machine to check the SD card files with? I wonder if your 3D printer is reading from the file's *meta data* rather than the file name itself ... 

Comment: I realize this doesn't answer your question, but if you have a spare Raspberry Pi, consider using [Octorpint](https://octoprint.org/) instead of an SD card...